# Why does this code only crash on 9.0 Pie?

Tags: android

**EDIT** - See stack trace at bottom..

I recently launched an app for a client, and the 5th person to test had the app crash immediately after opening. I asked them to send a crash report and I literally have a video of them doing it. It's been 32 hours and no crash report has come in yet.

Every device I have tested the app on plus google's pre-launch checklist gave the app the green lights. So far the it's their Pixel XL 2 that crashes during the splash screen. I am unable to obtain one for testing. Here is the assumed file that crashes.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);


    deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared_location", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(Splash.this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);

            getLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Splash.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Splash.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    } else {

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);

        getLocationUpdates();
        token = Utils.getToken(Splash.this, Constant.TOKEN);
    }


}

Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet(); // true or false
            if (isInternetPresent) {

                RefreshData nearest = new RefreshData();
                nearest.execute();

            } else if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

                RefreshData nearest = new RefreshData();
                nearest.execute();


            } else {

                Common_class.Alert(Splash.this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                    double latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();

                    strLatitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
                    strLongitude = String.valueOf(longitude);


                    editor.putString("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
                    editor.putString("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
                    editor.commit();

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Splash.class);
                    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    finish();


                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Common_class.settingsRequest(Splash.this);
                    break;
            }


        case PERM_REQUEST_CODE_DRAW_OVERLAYS:

            if (requestCode == PERM_REQUEST_CODE_DRAW_OVERLAYS) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {   //Android M Or Over
                    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                        // ADD UI FOR USER TO KNOW THAT UI for SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission was not granted earlier...
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

public void getLocationUpdates() {
    if (gpsTracker.isGPSEnabled) {

        double latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();


        editor.putString("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
        editor.putString("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
        editor.commit();


        Intent service = new Intent(Splash.this, MyService.class);
        startService(service);
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.start();

    } else {

        selectAlert();


    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                getLocationUpdates();
                token = Utils.getToken(Splash.this, Constant.TOKEN);

            } 
            //getLocationUpdates();

            break;
    }
}


public void selectAlert() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);
    builder.setMessage("Gps is off. Please select one of the following options.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Turn on GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Common_class.settingsRequest(Splash.this);

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Select your area", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent it = new Intent(Splash.this, Select_area.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                    finish();

                }
            });

    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}


public class RefreshData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url = "http://138.197.133.79/pocketdeal/onsplashscreen";
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("android_id", deviceId));


        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));

            HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();

            String res = httpresponse.getStatusLine().toString();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if (s != null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (null != activeNetworkInfo) {
        if(activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            //we have WIFI
            Log.e("Splash", "Wifi");
        }
        if(activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            //we have cellular data
            Log.e("Splash", "Mobile");
        }
    } else{
        //we have no connection :(
        Log.e("Splash", "No Connection");
    }

    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

}
```

The code is sadly a bit ugly and un-commented, it is in the work schedule to clean up the semi-untouched files.
Some guesses on the bug are..
 - The AsyncTask class could cause leaks, but haven't experience any so I left that for now
 - The get string for device ID, ideally this is not how I would have set up the app, is it possible Pixel XL 2 is flagging this?

I would try fixing things but being I can't test this I am not sure what would be correct without launching to production. Going to see what I can find on various emulators & swapping out GPS Tracker as suggested below.

**EDIT** Stacktrace was recieved from emulator crash!

```
2018-11-29 18:56:39.210 6894-6928/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals, PID: 6894
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient;
    at ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals.ui.Splash$RefreshData.doInBackground(Splash.java:293)
    at ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals.ui.Splash$RefreshData.doInBackground(Splash.java:287)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class  "org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  2018-11-29 18:56:39.217 6894-6928/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 8 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals-OfYsYiwwFsKYODoG_6dWtA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    2018-11-29 18:56:39.272 1607-1607/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/6894/oom_score_adj; errno=22
      2018-11-29 18:56:39.437 1955-2080/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '2ac2a3b ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals/ca.deals.pocket.pocketdeals.ui.Splash (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
   2018-11-29 18:56:43.068 1955-2153/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
  2018-11-29 18:56:43.706 1955-1971/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
  2018-11-29 18:56:43.743 1955-1971/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

I resolved the stack trace with this code - `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`

Now it opens up new problems but that is for me to solve.

Comment: If its crashing, post the stack trace.

Comment: Also, BIG red flag is using GPSTracker-  assuming its the ussual implementation, its broken, buggy, and been known that nobody should EVER use it for a decade now.

Comment: Gabe - it's not crashing for me though, only on this one phone it has been received as crashing. I will take a look at replacing that, most of the code I received was deprecated.

Comment: Stack Trace came in now on an emulator of the Pixel XL 2, see what you think.

Comment: You're using a deprecated HTTP library that was removed completely on newer Android device.  Change it to using URLConnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After receiving the stack trace I found the solution to be

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

It appears to be an issue with apache targeting 9.0 Pie

As said by Gabe:

> You're using a deprecated HTTP library that was removed completely on newer Android device. Change it to using URLConnection

While Android Studio did not flag this it may come up in the future

Comment: it works for me thanks C. Skjerdal just put this command inside the application tag

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the allocated ram size of pixel 2 xl emulator and increase its internal space by going inside adv manager then restart the Android studio and Adv

Comment: I was literally having issues with the emulator just now, I will try this!

Comment: This helped the emulator run great, but now I have a stack trace for the crash that caused it. Feel free to check out!